# Dynamic ax 2012 R2 Send pdf file to printer on server side

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying send pdf file to printer using soap client from web.
Using job in ax works fine.
I'am tried:
 winAPI::shellExecute(adobeExe,  adobeParm);
Enable AOS printing on the AOS server
 
http://www.artofcreation.be/2014/01/27/how-to-print-any-file-in-ax/
But does not work for me.
Maybe for someone has managed to do it? 
Maybe need with ghostScript or sumatraPDF ? or...? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

```
#File   //File macro
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
System.Diagnostics.Process process;
System.Exception interopException;

// Parameters
Filename    fileName    = @"C:\test\test.pdf";
PrinterName printername = UserPrinterHandler::getDefaultPrinter();
;

printerName = '"' + printerName + '"';

try
{
    // assert permissions
    new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop).assert();

    process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    processInfo = process.get_StartInfo();

    processInfo.set_UseShellExecute(true);
    processInfo.set_CreateNoWindow(true);
    processInfo.set_FileName(fileName);

    // the argument is the printer name
    processInfo.set_Arguments(printerName);

    // set the verb to printto
    processInfo.set_Verb('printto');
    processInfo.set_WindowStyle(System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden);

    process.Start();

    // revert asserted permissions
    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Log into the server as the `AOS user account` and make sure the printer is added, or re-add it.  Can't hurt to do it again as your user account too.

Comment: I get default exception error.Printers is added 
I check  with pjs = new PrintJobSettings();
 pjs.getNumberOfPrinters()